# How to start named -u bind automatically on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bind

I have two Ubuntu 14.04 x64 boxes. One is normal install, the other one is minimum install. I install `bind9` in both box. The normal install box works without any problem. However, I can not add new zone to the minimum install. When I tried to add new zone using `rndc`, it has the following error message:

```
rndc: connect failed: 127.0.0.1#953: connection refused
```

I Googled around, and found the process `named` is not running on the minimum install. After I manually run:

```
named -u bind
service bind9 restart
```

it works properly. So my question is how I can make the minimum install be the same like the normal install, to start `named -u bind` automatically? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems problem solved by answering `y` when being asked while installing `bind9`.

```
Configuration file '/etc/init.d/bind9'
 ==> File on system created by you or by a script.
 ==> File also in package provided by package maintainer.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** bind9 (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? y
```